# Using map with additional parameters - python

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, dictionary, typeerror

I have a function to measure text length:

```
def length(text, option='char'):
  if option == 'char':
    return len(text) - text.count(' ')
  elif option == 'token':
    return text.count(' ') + 1
```

I can get the character text length:

```
texts = ['this is good', 'foo bar sentence', 'hello world']
text_lens = map(length, texts)
print text_lens
```

But how do i specify the 2nd parameter in the function when i'm using `map`?

The following code:

```
texts = ['this is good', 'foo bar sentence', 'hello world']
text_lens = map(length(option='token'), texts)
print text_lens
```

gives this error:

```
TypeError: length() takes at least 1 argument (1 given)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.partial):

```
text_lens = map(functools.partial(length, option='token'), texts)
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you can use [`lambda`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#lambda):

```
text_lens = map(lambda x: length(x, 'token'), texts)

text_lens = map(lambda x: length(x, option='token'), texts)
```

Comment: i like `lambda` but my collaborators don't, sigh... got to go with the `functools.partial` for now...

Comment: @alvas, No problem. BTW, sometimes, you can't use `functools.partial`. For example, if `length` function had no keyword argument: `def length(text, option):`, you can't use `partial` for `option`.

Comment: @falsetru: You can still specify `option='token'` to the partial if `option` has no default value. The problems occur when you try to specify middle positional arguments or the positional-only arguments some of the functions written in C have.

Answer (score 2):

In most cases a list comprehension / generator is preferable to `map`. It offers all the power of map with a couple of added features.

```
text_lens = [length(item, option="token") for item in texts]
```